# Django Rest Framework - Translating external unique code to a internal id and vice versa

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a Rest Api that read and update a model called Requirements.
I am using a ModelSerializer.
The Requirements model has a foreign key on the Materials model.

The problem is that my api user does not know the internal id of Materials
He knows only a code that is unique for the material.
Now, the idea is that in PUT he passes me the material_code and I set the material id and in GET he receives the material code based on the material foreign key of Requirements

I managed to make PUT to work by overriding the validate method and declaring:
    
    `material_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=50);`

This is the code supplied in the end of the post. Notice, please, that this is a snippet of the complete code that is much complex. In the complete code the Requirements serializer is nested inside another serializer that is nested is nested inside another serializer. But I do not think this is relevant to the problem.

Then I manage to make GET to work by the use of a custom source option in material_code field where the source is a property on my Requirements model. For this the declaration must be changed to:

```
material_code = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='get_material_code')
```

For some reason both:

```
material_code = serializers.Field()
```

and

```
material_code = serializers.Field(source='get_material_code')
```

behaves in a weird way and do not work either with PUT or with GET, raising an exception “Field.to_internal_value() must be implemented”. I've tried to implement to_internal_value and give it a try but failed. And after all, material_code should not go to a internal value. Once I've managed to set the material id, I do not need it.

There is no way I can make both PUT and GET work simultaneously. GET will only work with serializers.ReadOnlyField and PUT with a serializers.CharField.

Using PUT with serializers.ReadOnlyField generates Exception Type:  KeyError Exception Value 'material_code'.

Using GET with serializers.CharField generates Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `material_code` on serializer `RequirementsSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Requirements` instance. Original exception text was: 'Requirements' object has no attribute 'material_code'.

Maybe the whole approach is wrong. 
What I need is a translation between the externally visible code and the internal id.
This should not be that hard. This is my first Python project and maybe there is a built in way do make it work in Django Rest Api, but I was unable to find in the documentation.

I will deeply appreciate any help. By the way, this is my first stackoverflow post. If I did anything wrong, please let me know.

```
class Materials (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'materials'
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50);
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Requirements (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'requirements'
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materials, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    acceptance_method = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    @property
    def get_material_code(self):
        return self.material.code


 class RequirementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    material_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=50);
    material = serializers.HiddenField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        model = Requirements
        fields = [  'id',
                    'material' ,
                    'material_code' ,
                    'acceptance_method'
        ]
        read_only_fields = ['material']


    def validate(self, data):
      # Fill material with a pk on Materials models
      # This is necessary since the API receive a material code instead of the model id
      if Materials.objects.filter(code = data['material_code']).exists() :
         data['material'] = Materials.objects.get(code = data['material_code'])
      else: 
         raise serializers.ValidationError('Material '+ data['material_code'] + ' does not exists')
      return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want the user to be able to do a `PUT` using the material code as the identifier of the material (instead of the ID), and you want the same behavior from the `GET` call. If this is the case, I believe you are looking for the [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) of serializers. Example:

```
class RequirementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    material = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='code')
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I do not have reputation enough do vote but you have my gratitude. I was hoping that the answer was much easier than my attempt.
I had to make one minor adjustment.  

material = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='code', queryset=Materials.objects.all())